# How to make table header with 2 rows sticky?! (without js)

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-position, sticky

I have two rows in my table header and I want it to be fixed on scroll. How can I do this? I've tried setting the position of `th` elements to `sticky`, but the second row overlaps the first on scroll (see snippet).

**I've seen lots of js based solutions to this, but am not interested in them at all. Surely it's possible using just CSS!**

**I'd also rather not a solution where you have to hard code the height of your header rows.**

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
  background: red;
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background: blue;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>b</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>c</th>
        <th>d</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>k</td>
        <td>l</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>m</td>
        <td>n</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>o</td>
        <td>p</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>q</td>
        <td>r</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>s</td>
        <td>t</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>u</td>
        <td>v</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>w</td>
        <td>x</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>y</td>
        <td>z</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They become sticky but overlay over each other.
You need to specify the `top` of the second row to be with a space of the first row.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
  background: red;
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background: blue;
  text-align: left;
}

thead>tr:nth-child(2) th {
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>b</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>c</th>
        <th>d</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>k</td>
        <td>l</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>m</td>
        <td>n</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>o</td>
        <td>p</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>q</td>
        <td>r</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>s</td>
        <td>t</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>u</td>
        <td>v</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>w</td>
        <td>x</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>y</td>
        <td>z</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```